# Proving the existence of neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:{\bf R}\rightarrow{\bf R}$ and let $a\in{\bf R}$.

Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $f(a)>0$, then there exists a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in I$.

This is what I have so far:

Since $f$ is continuous at $a$, $a$ belongs to $E'$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)=f(a)$. Because $a$ belongs to $E'$, every neighborhood, $I$, of $a$ contains infinetely many points of $f$. Let y satisfy $y>0$, $f(a)$. There exists $x\in I \setminus \{a\}$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus, there is a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $f(x)>0$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what $E^\prime$ is in your proof? One simpler way to solve this problem is to argue as follows, using directly the definition of continuity.

Take $\epsilon := \frac{f(a)}{2} > 0$. Because $f$ is continuous at $a$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
 \left\vert f(x) - f(a) \right\vert < \epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x-a| < \delta$. Then, it follows that
\begin{align*}
f(a) - f(x) \leq |f(x)-f(a)| < \frac{f(a)}{2}
\end{align*}
for all such $x$. But, this means that
$$
f(x) > \frac{f(a)}{2} > 0
$$
for all $x \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$. The claim then follows with $I := (a-\delta, a+\delta)$.

Comment: I believe that it is the set of accumulation points of E.

Comment: @lj_growl Given $y >0$ arbitrary, how can you ensure that there exists $x \in I \setminus \{a\}$ such that $f(x) = y$? This would fail for $f(x) = 1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with $y = 2$, say. Moreover, this does not imply that the required $I$ exists.